# Why does importing a TypeScript module disallow existing module extension?

Tags: typescript, amd

I have a TypeScript external definition file (foo.d.ts):

```
declare module foo {
    export class bar {
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this (in baz.ts):

```
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />
module foo {
    class baz extends bar {
    }
}
```

So far so good. But when I import some other TypeScript file compiled as an AMD module compilation breaks:

```
module foo {
    class baz extends bar { // Error: could not find symbol "bar"
    }
}

import T1 = module("test1"); // Removing this line resolves the compilation error
```

The AMD file being imported is a simple as:

```
export var NAME = "NAME";
```

Does anybody know if this is intended? Why does `import` break my code in such a way?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a bug in typescript compiler.

Please try the following,
Removed the reference
"reference path="foo.d.ts" 
and add

```
import f = module("foo.d");
module foo {
    class baz extends f.foo.bar {
    }
}
```

I am not sure how will be the output .js. But by doing this it is not giving error in visual studio.